# How to show two columns in a CollectionView using swift4 in all devices

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

[image]

To show only two columns in a collectionView i am using this piece of code

```
    let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width:(self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 10)/2,height: (self.collectionView.frame.size.height)/3)
```

but it is only showing properly on 5s, not on every iphone. please help.

i want to show my view controller like this image. please help anyone

[image]

Comment: Bangali naki? @Gorib

Comment: mone prane @iPeter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add this code to **viewDidLoad**.
change height according to you.

try this!

```
if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        let size = CGSize(width:(collectionView!.bounds.width-30)/2, height: 250)
        layout.itemSize = size
}
```

Answer (score 51):

You must be missing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Try this and see:

```
// Source code
import UIKit

class CollectionVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //collection.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let flowayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let space: CGFloat = (flowayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
        let size:CGFloat = (collection.frame.size.width - space) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testcell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell
    }

}
```

// Interface Design

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: can you tell me how reduce the space between two items.

Comment: done it accordingly but the space between two items is not reducing sir

Comment: @GoribDeveloper - Copy my full code and design your interface exactly I've shown in interface builder design.

Comment: Create a new sample project and try this code and in it. May be other extension features affecting in your existing project

Comment: yes.i also thought that.. okay doing it accordingly

Comment: This is a pretty elegant answer - I like how it takes into the account whatever insets you may set - thank you!

Comment: This does not work on iOS 14.6 unfortunately.  I get 3 columns with it instead of two

Comment: @DeepakSharma -  Let me check for iOS 14 and get back to you.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure your protocol confirms to your **ViewController**,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

And set **flow layout** to your **collectionview** object

In **viewDidLoad**

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //.horizontal
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
```

And implement following methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)//here your custom value for spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let lay = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let widthPerItem = collectionView.frame.width / 2 - lay.minimumInteritemSpacing
    
    return CGSize(width:widthPerItem, height:100)
}
```

Comment: doing it accordingly

Comment: @karthikeyani am saying that i am following your steps

Comment: yes.. it is coming..can you tell me how reduce the space between two items.

Comment: let us know, if that helps you

Comment: change your values here return  UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)

Comment: the space is not reducing sir

Comment: give layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)

Comment: adjust your values depends upon your need, this is the proper way to adding flowlayout programmatically

Comment: are you adding like this let widthPerItem = collectionView.frame.width / 2 - lay.minimumInteritemSpacing

Comment: what is your result now

Comment: the space is not reducing.. between two items
      let size = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 30) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)

Comment: Never give static values like 30

Comment: okay sir doing this let lay = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
            let widthPerItem = collectionView.frame.width / 2 - lay.minimumInteritemSpacing

return CGSize(width:widthPerItem, height:100)

Comment: Work for me. The CollectionView is inside UITableCellView

Comment: Working Solution

Answer (score 1):

I have following code which I have implemented to display two column in collection view.

Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`’s following method method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = (collectionView.frame.size.width - 30) / 2
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Where 30 stand for left, right and middle space between cell.

i.e Cell should be add 10 pixel on left Side, 10 pixel on right side and 10 pixel in between two cell.

Select you `collectionview` from storyboard and from Size Inspector set following minimum spacing.

I hope this will fix you issue.

Let me know if any query.

[image]

Comment: What happening ?

Comment: posting screenshot

Comment: Have you connected collectionView’s Delegate ?

Comment: where i have to give 30?

Comment: Can you share your demo if not a project ?

Answer (score 1):

Update for Swift 5 and XCode 12.4

```
    import UIKit

class TwoColumnViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Section {
        case main
    }

    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>! = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Two-Column Grid"
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
}

extension TwoColumnViewController {
    /// - Tag: TwoColumn
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                             heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .absolute(44))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)
        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }
}

extension TwoColumnViewController {
    func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
            // Populate the cell with our item description.
            cell.label.text = "\(identifier)"
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .cornflowerBlue
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.label.textAlignment = .center
            cell.label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            // Return the cell.
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }

        // initial data
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Int>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(Array(0..<94))
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```