# UICollectionViewCell spacing to fill maximum area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

First time using a UICollectionView if you can believe it, and I'm wondering how to get the cells to basically fill out the maximum allowed space.

The the view for the SE, it's filling out... mostly OK and how I want it.  Sure, I'd like the blocks to go all the way to the bottom of the black area (colors are temporary of course), but it's close enough.

[image]

On the iPhone X, and other larger screened phones of course, it maintains the "minimum" spacing, but what I'd like it to do is to auto adjust the spacing so that they fill out the area.  Top two blocks at the top and bottom two blocks at the the bottom, with equally distributed space in between.

[image: collection view iphone x]

Oddly enough, I was able to achieve this quite easily when I did it manually with each of them in the regular view.  I started trying to use a `UICollectionView` because it started to really look ugly once it rotated into landscape mode.  Here's a shot of how those items were setup using the more manual method.
[image]

[image: collection view attributes]
[image: collection view size inspector]

Any suggestions?  Seems like something that'd be an easy switch... but I seem to have hit a wall and am stumped.  Am I missing something so blatantly obvious here, or what?!?

---

Oh, and I've also toyed with using:

```
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

To set the spacing of the line items programmatically, but that wasn't without problems either.  In there, I was checking for the screen height, dividing by the count of items and using a variation of that as the spacing.

That seemed to "*work*" at first.

But in my testing, that function only fires when the view is very first loaded, and then *only* when it goes **into** landscape mode.  When it comes **out** and goes back to portrait, it doesn't re-fire and recalculate.  Thus... keeping the (now new) landscape spacing.

Comment: What is your item width and size? You may need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573790/how-to-show-two-columns-in-a-collectionview-using-swift4-in-all-devices/49574224#49574224

Answer (score 0):

You need to create UICollectionViewFlowLayout and compute size of the items programmatically.

Or override UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout item size.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview